# Lifespan of Tags on Deleted Questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, automation, tag-deletion

Taken from the [Create Tags help on Math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> On some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.

Does the script that culls these tags consider tags on **deleted** questions?

Comment: Tags get automatically removed after a day if they are not linked to **any** question.

Comment: @juergen I mistakenly thought that what I read applied to *all* tags. I found the exact excerpt, and it applies only to *new* tags. I rephrased the question to be more specific.